# Why does this AutoHotKey script occasionally not execute the first 250 lines?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, autohotkey, byte-order-mark

[This AutoHotKey script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjf7fe0gc9m2m1d/Quacau.ahk?dl=0) contains a list of Unicode hotstrings. In my best understanding, occasionally the first 250 lines doesn't run. And when that happens, the last hotstrings don't output correctly. For example, for the hotstring

```
:*:nnc::Nghiên cứu triết học phương Đông
```

the output would be:

```
Nghi3n cứu triết học ph[]ng )4ng
```

The script is encoded in UTF-8_BOM, as recommended in [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/9zz9q3/why_do_hotstrings_sometimes_dont_work_depending/ead8viu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: A few characters seem to be translated - try option `T` or `R` like [the manual suggests](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#raw).

Comment: why are they translated?